# Showing "Username Accepted" message using JSON and ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

I have created a method that checks the database for duplication of usernames and then displays a message using JSON that the username is not available if already taken.

Although everything seems to work fine, I cant get to display the a success message if the username is new such as "Username Accepted"  using JSON. Below is my method which works perfectly, just want it to display a success message too.

Can anyone guide me on it.. ?

```
public JsonResult doesUsernameExist(string UserName)
{
      //Fetch usernames from the database.
      var userNames = UserServiceInstance.GetAllUsers().Where(a => a.UserName == UserName);

      if (userNames.Count() > 0)
          return Json(string.Format("{0} is not available.", UserName), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
      else
        return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this way:

```
if(userNames.Count() > 0)
    return Json(new { Success = false, Message = "This username is taken"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
else 
    return Json(new { Success = true, Message = "Username accepted"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Then on client side where you make Ajax call to server, inside callback method:

```
...
success: function(response){
   if(response.Success){
      // user name accepted, do what ever you want, e.g alert response.Message
      ...  
   }else{
      // user name taken
      ...
   }
}
```

Hope that helps.